# How to get VSCode to add a comma after the `}` it has just autocompleted?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

If I try to write a method inside an object initializer, for example by typing:

```
myFunction() {
```

then vscode adds a `}`, leaving me to manually add the `,`.

Is there a way to get it to always add `},`?

I should note that in my coding standards, all object properties should end with a comma (ie including the final one).

I'm running vscode 1.13.0 on Windows 10 (outside WSL).

Comment: have you figured it out? I have the same question but the only answer doesn't seem resolved it.

Comment: No, sorry....I gave up on VSCode and Windows too, and went back to Ubuntu and gvim :)

Comment: that's sad. Can't imagine so many javascript developers are just manually moving cursors around to complete a sentence..

Comment: I'm am only one, and I've been using vi{,m} since 1986 - lots of muscle memory. It is a general frustration to me that vscode (et al) keep filling in things and displaying things unnecessarily. NB, I don't have to 'manually move a cursor around to complete a sentence' in vim - I just type it. On the contrary, it is with vscode that I have to manually move the cursor around in order to correct what it has unhelpfully done "for me". I don't know why you would be 'sad' because my tool works much better for me - you should be happy :)

Comment: I was using python/java in IntelliJ like editor. {} are just automatically added if I do keyboard short like ctrl+shift+enter, and it can also intelligently tell whether you are going to the next line from if (so to add {}) or from a plain statement (so to just add ; behind). VScode is so popular in the world for Javascript and I'm sad that nobody gives it a shout for missing such an intelligent common feature that other IDE do.

Comment: btw, you started vim earlier than I was born.. that is amazing!

Comment: I think most people 'give it a shout' - indeed, that is why I went and gave it a try. I don't much case for IDEs in general, tbh. They seem to do things I can easily do myself, and I've learned to do them myself so I end up doing them twice, and having to correct it. EG - it puts in a closing bracket when I open one...it's just irritating. The value I've noticed is from syntax checking and such like, and a good linter is good enough for me and they usually work just fine no matter what editor it being used.

Comment: BTW, I didn't start using vim then - back then it was 'vi' - that's why said "vi{,m}" (which expands to 'vi vim' - a bashism). It's not really so amazing. Back then, there were no such things as IDEs - unless you count Emacs (spit ;)), so it's really a matter of how long ago it was, and there have been plenty of people born since then...ie, you are not alone :)
I suppose it is now probably true that there are more people alive since 1986 than before 1986...*definitely*, there are more coders.

Comment: TBH, I once saw a coder using VSCode, and she (yes, a woman, which was unusual enough) just *flew*. Very impressive. So, I know it can be used very efficiently.
On the other hand, I know a lot of vim users who use vim MUCH more effectively than I do - I'm very much still in the 'vi' world compared to the 'vim' world. I get by quite well though, I think.
It would be nice to be able to switch editors/IDEs/etc more easily, and sometimes I try, but I usually end up going back and feeling all my muscles 'relax' having done so. Bit like moving back to Linux from Windows/Mac. I started on Unix.

Comment: Man, I wish there was a clean solution to this. It would save so much of boring typing fatigue :)

Answer (score 2):

**Automatically add JSON/JavaScript Object comma**.

> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LeonQin.auto-insert-comma

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) with the [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) extension.

ESLint is able to "Fix" some of the rules automatically. For this one — [comma-dangle](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle).

`.eslintrc` or `.eslintrc.json` or some other eslint config file:

```
{
    //...
    "rules": {
        "comma-dangle": [1, {
            "objects": "always",
            "arrays": "ignore",
            "imports": "ignore",
            "exports": "ignore",
            "functions": "ignore"
        }]
    }
}
```

`settings.json`:

```
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true
```

P.S. ESLint can auto fix some other things like indentation, spacing, semicolons, parentheses, curly braces, ...

Comment: Thanks. I guess that might work well enough, but it does seem like vscode itself is helping me by adding a '}'; but why not also add a ','. In most cases, it's a syntax error to not have a comma, so it seems like it should add one, no? Is it deliberate?